# Spring WebFlux. How to get the request body in two different formats using @RequestBody annotation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux

I'm using Spring Boot 2.5.6 and Spring WebFlux. In my business case, I need to use the HTTP request body in two different forms:

1. Raw JSON string
2. Already parsed Java DTO

There are my `RestContoller`:

```java
@PostMapping("/play")
public Mono<PlayResponse> play(@RequestBody PlayCommand parsedBody,
                               @RequestBody String jsonBody) {
    //code here
}
```

When I run tests I get the next exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only one connection receive subscriber allowed.
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.startReceiver(FluxReceive.java:182) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.12.jar:1.0.12]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ HTTP POST "/play" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
```

When I use the next method signature:

```java
@PostMapping("/play")
public Mono<PlayResponse> play(PlayCommand playCommand,
                               @RequestBody String body){
    //code here
}
```

`PlayCommand parsedBody` has all fields is set to 'null'.
I can't find a way to receive the body properly.

I understand, that I can use `objectMapper` and convert `playCommand` back to JSON, but this is additional work that does not need to be done.
Is it possible to receive the request body in two different forms? Or maybe, I'm doing something wrong in my examples?

Comment: No you can read the body only once. Why would you need it both as the raw payload and serialized to the object? What is your usecase, what are you trying to solve?

Comment: @M.Deinum I wanna verify the request signature and then handle other work.

Comment: Do that as part of your flow not in your controller. Write a `WebFilter` that validates the signature, if it fails abort the flow/return an error.

Comment: @M.Deinum I've tried to do exactly what you suggest. In the case of `WebFilter`, I got a hardly-understandable code (It has a problem with reading of raw body too). I have only 3 controller methods with such behavior and for this reason, I decided to follow a simple, clear path with 'two bodies'... Which doesn't work.

Comment: There is only 1 body so no you cannot do this with 2 arguments. You would need to do the serializing yourself and validate in your method. Also now you have 3 until you don't have 3 but 10 of these then you really want a separate crosscutting concern for this. You also might want to use `Mono<String>` instead of `String` as the body, that way you can do the validation before the mapping to an object in your code (and maybe make it partially reusable).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I agree with you, in the case of 10 - much better to use `WebFilter` and I will. I tried to use `Mono<String>` in the current implementation and It works well.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having multiple `@RequestBody` is not possible. If you really need both original JSON and its serialized version the best you can do is receive the request body as a plain `String` and then convert it to the corresponding Java object as follows:

```java
@Autowired
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

@PostMapping("/play")
public Mono<PlayResponse> play(@RequestBody String body){
    PlayCommand playCommand = objectMapper.readValue(body, PlayCommand.class);
}
```