# Get body as raw string from ServerWebExchange/ServerHttpRequest

Tags: java, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I need to get the request body as a raw JSON string in my controller. I'm using Spring WebFlux. If I could change ***@PostMapper*** function signature, it will be so easy to get the raw JSON by using "***@RequestBody String rawStudent***". But I can't do that as it's auto-generated and will affect other handlers, also "***@RequestBody Student***" already exist and we can't have two @RequestBody.

```
@RestController
public class StudentController {
    @PostMapping("/student")
    private void newStudent(@RequestBody Student student,
                            ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        String rawStudent = ServerExchangeUtils.getRequestRawBody(exchange); //idealy like this
        System.out.println(rawStudent);
    }
}
```

What I'm looking for is something like "getRequestRaw(exchange)"

Comment: duplicate? [Spring WebFlux. How to get the request body in two different formats using @RequestBody annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69797121/spring-webflux-how-to-get-the-request-body-in-two-different-formats-using-requ)

Comment: @Toerktumlare I saw that one thanks. But as I said, I can't change the signature.

Comment: You can just convert Student to a string with a JSON library such as Jackson.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not possible in my case. I need the exact raw json body as it was sent: same indentations, same white spaces,..etc.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem and i cant change the signaure because it is generated by openapi generator

i found a solution by caching the body in a string in a WebFilter :

```
@Slf4j
public class CachingBodyServerHttpRequestDecorator extends ServerHttpRequestDecorator {

private final StringBuilder cachedBody = new StringBuilder();

public CachingBodyServerHttpRequestDecorator(ServerHttpRequest delegate) {
    super(delegate);
}

@Override
public Flux<DataBuffer> getBody() {
    return super.getBody().doOnNext(this::cache);
}

@SneakyThrows
private void cache(DataBuffer buffer) {
    cachedBody.append(UTF_8.decode(buffer.asByteBuffer()));
}

public String getCachedBody() {
    return cachedBody.toString();
}
}


public final class CachingBodyServerWebExchangeDecorator extends ServerWebExchangeDecorator {

private final ServerHttpRequestDecorator requestDecorator;

public CachingBodyServerWebExchangeDecorator(ServerWebExchange delegate) {
    super(delegate);
    this.requestDecorator = new CachingBodyServerHttpRequestDecorator(delegate.getRequest());
}

@Override
public ServerHttpRequest getRequest() {
    return requestDecorator;
}

}


@Component
@Slf4j
public class SetRequestBodyAttribute implements WebFilter {

    private static ServerHttpRequestPredicate requestsToServe =
            MethodServerHttpRequestPredicate.of(HttpMethod.POST)
                    .and(PathServerHttpRequestPredicate.of("/contacts/import"))
                    .or(MethodServerHttpRequestPredicate.of(HttpMethod.PATCH)
                            .and(PathServerHttpRequestPredicate.of("/contacts/{contact_id}")));

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        if (requestsToServe.test(exchange.getRequest())) {
             
        return chain.filter(new CachingBodyServerWebExchangeDecorator(exchange));
        }
        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }
}


@UtilityClass
public class ServerHttpRequestUtils {

    public Mono<String> getBodyAsString(ServerHttpRequest request) {
        return Mono.just(((CachingBodyServerHttpRequestDecorator)exchange.getRequest()).getCachedBody())
    }
}


public interface ServerHttpRequestPredicate {

    boolean test(ServerHttpRequest request);

    @NotNull
    default ServerHttpRequestPredicate and(@NotNull ServerHttpRequestPredicate other) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(other);
        return (t) -> test(t) && other.test(t);
    }

    @NotNull
    default ServerHttpRequestPredicate negate() {
        return (t) -> !test(t);
    }

    @NotNull
    default ServerHttpRequestPredicate or(@NotNull ServerHttpRequestPredicate other) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(other);
        return (t) -> test(t) || other.test(t);
    }
}

@Value
public class PathServerHttpRequestPredicate implements ServerHttpRequestPredicate {

    public static PathServerHttpRequestPredicate of(String path) {
        return new PathServerHttpRequestPredicate(path);
    }

    PathPattern pathPattern;

    public PathServerHttpRequestPredicate(String path) {
        Assert.notNull(path, "path should not be null!");
        this.pathPattern = PathPatternParser.defaultInstance.parse(path);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean test(ServerHttpRequest request) {
        PathContainer pathContainer = request.getPath().pathWithinApplication();
        PathPattern.PathMatchInfo info = this.pathPattern.matchAndExtract(pathContainer);
        return info != null;
    }
}

@Value(staticConstructor = "of")
public class MethodServerHttpRequestPredicate implements ServerHttpRequestPredicate{

    HttpMethod httpMethod;

    public MethodServerHttpRequestPredicate(HttpMethod httpMethod) {
        Assert.notNull(httpMethod, "httpMethod should not be null!");
        this.httpMethod = httpMethod;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean test(ServerHttpRequest request) {
        return request.getMethod() == httpMethod;
    }
}
```

and in the controller handler we can get the body as string even if it was injected as Object

```
Mono<String> bodyAsStringMono = ServerHttpRequestUtils .getBodyAsString(exchange);
```

Comment: how are you clearing the cache?